# Not in / in query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to retrieve the emails that aren't in the main table dbo.a_customer

when I run this query I retrieve zero results .

```
select email from dbo.CVbank 
where email NOT in (select email from dbo.a_customer)
```

Though when I run this I retrieve 24206 results

```
select email from dbo.CVbank 
where email in (select email from dbo.a_customer)
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Thanks

Ethan

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that all the records in `CVBank` also exist in `a_customer`?

Comment: Ok, all emails are in the customer table.  Is that an issue?

Comment: It saying that all emails are in the customer table but when I run the query "where email in " i get 24206 results when there are 65952 emails in cvbank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query probably isn't doing what you expect:

```
select c.email
from dbo.CVbank c
where c.email NOT in (select email from dbo.a_customer);
```

The problem is that if `a_customer.email` is ever `NULL`, then the result is false for all values of `c.email`.  You can fix this by adding a specific condtiion:

```
select c.email
from dbo.CVbank c
where c.email NOT in (select email from dbo.a_customer where email is not NULL);
```

However, it is safer just to use `not exists`.  This formulation doesn't have this "problem" with `NULL`s (this is not really a problem, it is how `NULL` values work in SQL, but it is unexpected behavior):

```
select c.email
from dbo.CVbank c
where not exists (select 1 from dbo.a_customer ac where ac.email = c.email);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon this worked :)